# buttons turns into colors css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put CSS design to my code and green on the parent button and yellow on the child button

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  var counter = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-counter'));
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.id = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.setAttribute('data-counter', '1');
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction(this)');
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  btn.setAttribute('data-counter', ++counter);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_rv" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-counter="1">Main Button</button>
```

Comment: <button id="btn_rv" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-counter="1">Main Button</button>

Comment: So if I assume correct, `Main Button` is parent button and newly added buttons are child. right?

Comment: yes sir. but everytime i click the child button all the colors reset and the new parent and child shows the color

Answer (score 1):

This code does the following:

- reset all buttons' colors to default
- change currently clicked button's color to green
- changes child's button color to yellow

Modify the code according to your requirements.

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  btn.style.background='green';
  var counter = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-counter'));
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.id = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.setAttribute('data-counter', '1');
  button.setAttribute('onclick','myFunction(this)');
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  btn.setAttribute('data-counter', ++counter);
  button.style.background='yellow';
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_rv" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-counter="1">Main Button</button>
```

Comment: thats correct sir,but everytime i click another button, all the colors reset

Comment: His code works, if you click on a button (doesn't matter which one) it resets all the colors and sets green for the clicked button and yellow for the new one

Comment: sir when i click the present button the parent of the button lights *green*

Answer (score 0):

You should uses classes for any styling of elements. In-line styles can make your code repetitive and difficult to maintain.

#### Code

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  var counter = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-counter'));
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.id = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.setAttribute('data-counter', '1');
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction(this)');
  button.className = "child";
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  btn.setAttribute('data-counter', ++counter);
  btn.className = "parent"
}
```

```css
.parent{
  background:green;
}

.child{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_rv" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-counter="1">Main Button</button>
```